# Is there any logging library (ex. log4j) in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, logging

I am a new as3 developer. Using **trace** method can help to print messages to the output pane of flash ide. However, in some situations, we want the messages fewer. I have used the Log4j library in java that supports choice a log level for the specific package/class.

If you have any information about logging in actionscript 3, please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always first check the already posted questions

[Logging API for AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614663/logging-api-for-as3)

Answer (score 1):

Hi here are a few that I know of (some not included in previous link). As you can see there are quite a few so it's just a case of finding which one fits your style the best

- [AS3 Commons logging](http://www.as3commons.org/)
- [Spicelib logging framework](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.0/manual/spicelib-logging.php)
- [Thunderbolt](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/wiki/ThunderBoltAS3)
- [flashlogger](http://code.google.com/p/flashlogger/)
- [SOS logging platform](http://www.sos.powerflasher.com/)
- [Anthropod logging](http://arthropod.stopp.se/)
- [Peanut butter logger](http://pbking.com/blog/?p=89)
- [LuminicBox logging](http://code.google.com/p/luminicbox-log/)
- [Alcon logging](http://blog.hexagonstar.com/alcon/)
- [Monster Debugger debugging and logging tool](http://www.monsterdebugger.com/)
- [Xray debugging and logging (may have been abandoned)](http://osflash.org/xray)

Apologises to anyone I've missed, feel free to add on the end.